# Whats quicker: 30 separate queries, or 30 OR conditions?

Tags: mysql

I'm using a mysql database and need to retrieve keys from one table, to get the corresponding data to those keys from another table.

As an example: I got a friends-table where all of person X's friends are listed with their unique key. Additionally I got a users table, where all the user info is stored.
Now I wanna query all the information from the user table that belong to person X's 30 friends.
So whats quicker then:
Doing a loop with 30 iterations for every friend with the following query

```
SELECT name, age, location FROM users WHERE id=X
```

or doing the following query

```
SELECT name, age, location FROM users WHERE id=1 OR id=2 OR .... OR id=30
```

If one is quicker, is it always quicker, i.e. there's no break-even point?

Comment: Generally, the objective is as few round trips to the database as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [BETWEEN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between)

```
SELECT name, age, location FROM users WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 30
```

Note that `BETWEEN` is inclusive, and will include items with both id 1 and 30.

Another solution is using multi-condition

```
SELECT name, age, location FROM users  WHERE id >= 1 AND id <= 30
```

Also, another solution is using `IN` but you should write down all ranges

```
SELECT name, age, location FROM users WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...,30)
```

**update** 
 after you've updated the question, Generally one query with 30 conditions on an indexed field is faster than 30 queries **but using `BETWEEN` or `IN` operators has better performance than  both.**

Answer (score 4):

You must use `in`:

```
SELECT name, age, location FROM users WHERE id in(1, 2, 30)
```

One SQL query whith N rows will be faster then N queries with one row

Comment: I would add that a single query `SELECT column FROM table WHERE id IN (N1, N2, ...)` would outperform N queries for any number of N...

Comment: it is one query and result will be for N rows

Comment: `in(1, 2, 30)` is not true answer for this question and as I mentioned in my answer it should be  `IN(1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,... 30)`

Comment: @J.Litvak I commented only to point out the performance gain of this answer (since the OP had performance concerns which were not covered).

Comment: One sql query whith N rows will be faster then N queries with one row